# Return Data From '__main__' and Pipe large Stream to Python Script

Tags: python, pandas, pipe, multiprocessing

### Goal

I'm attempting to create a toy example of piping data to a python script that uses the `multiprocessing` library. Furthermore, this is code that will run on a web application, so please consider that in responses.

#### Issue #1

When the json `stream` becomes of certain length, it can no longer be input as an argument to my python script

#### Issue #2

I would like to return the data from the `'__main__'` function because the `multiprocessing` [needs to be run from the](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) `if name == '__main__':`

### Current Scripts

`run.py` has the following code:

```
import numpy
import pandas
import subprocess

#create a json stream to pipe
def create_stream(n_rows, n_cols): 
    df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(n_rows, n_cols))
    return df.to_json()


#pipe the json stream into the script multi_fun.py script
def test_multi(n_rows, n_cols):
    stream = create_stream(n_rows, n_cols)
    subprocess.call(["python", "multi_fun.py", stream])
```

`multi_fun.py` script has the following code:

```
import sys
import argparse
import pandas
from multiprocessing import Process


def get_maxes(df):
    d = {}
    for row in df.index:
        row_max = df.loc[row, :].max()
        print row_max
        d[row] = row_max
    return pandas.Series(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    usage = sys.argv[0] + "'json' stream"
    description = "toy multiprocessing"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = description, 
                                     usage = usage
    )

    parser.add_argument('stream', 
                        nargs = 1, 
                        type = str, 
                        help = 'json stream'
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    df = pandas.read_json(args.stream[0] , typ = 'frame')
    process = Process(target = get_maxes,   args = (df, ) )
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

### Example Execution

From iPython, things work fine when I'm using small numbers for the `DataFrame`

```
In [105]: import run

In [106]: run.test_multi(5,5)
1.2327553624
...
0.546843752

In [107]: run.test_multi(10, 10)
1.9811924526
1.059567146
....
1.6137051224
1.2899954045
```

But at higher numbers, I get this:

```
In [108]: run.test_multi(100, 100)
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long
```

### What I've tried (to Pipe in the Data)

I've tried passing `os.popen(stream)`, such as:

```
In [109:] subprocess.call(["python", "multi_fun.py", os.popen(stream)])
```

And likewise changing my `argparse` argument to `type = argparse.FileType('r')`, but I get a:

```
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Comment: You probably need to pass the stream to `stdin` of the child, rather than passing it as an argument at execution time.

Comment: @dano, I'm not following, what do you mean by "`stdin` of the child?" Are you referring to the child of the `subprocess.call` function or something else?

Comment: Right, I mean that you use `subprocess.Popen` to execute the child process, and then [`communicate(stdin_data)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to write the stream to the child's stdin. Then you rewrite your `multi_fun.py` script to read the stream from `sys.stdin`, rather than reading it as an argument.